# How do you choose certain VS Code theme features from light and from dark?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on a theme that has a dark UI and light editor. If in the `package.json` for my theme, under `contributes.themes.uiTheme` I can either specify `vs` or `vs-dark`. I use `vs`, then my icons are too dark. If I use `vs-dark`, then my icons are now light which is visible on a dark background, but the text select cursor is now white, which is hard to see on a white background.

Is there a way to change the settings to use the text select cursor from `vs` and the icons from `vs-dark`?

Comment: you can change (almost) all colors of the theme, what you pick in `uiTheme` is the default color if not changed and also where in the UI it will be shown

Comment: @rioV8 I've seen [Theme Color API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) but don't see anything about how to change file explorer icon color (I suspect you can't but there's two versions of icons, one for if the theme is `vs` and one for if it's `vs-dark) or how to change the text select cursor color (the actual OS's cursor, not the text selector in VS Code)